# Why does this Perl function return a value?

Tags: perl

```
   $hi = do_this('asdf');

   sub do_this
   {
       $blob{'f'} = {
          'k' => 'j'
      };
   }

   print $hi->{'k'};
   # prints j
```

since do_this doesn't return anything, how does it still print j?

Comment: Hopefully you are elsewhere in your code and we just don't see it in the snippet, but you should include `use strict; use warnings;`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html

> In the absence of an explicit return,
>   a subroutine, eval, or do FILE
>   automatically returns the value of the
>   last expression evaluated

Comment: also `do BLOCK` and any other block structure when it is in non-void context

Answer (score 4):

All Perl 5 subroutines return the last value of the last statement executed.

Comment: ...assuming they don't hit a `return` statement

Comment: @friedo: If they hit a `return` statement, what's the last statement executed? :P

Comment: Well, the less weird way to say that is the result of the last evaluated expression. That might not be the "last value" of since subroutines can return multiple items.